# groupby on Dask dataframe then sort by one column

Tags: pandas-groupby, dask

Imagine a simple Dask dataset with two columns:
- Transaction Date
- Transaction Amount

All i want to know is how to group by Transaction Date and show the count of transactions per day. I want the resulted dataframe sorted by Transaction Date or by count.
Here is my code:

`df = taxi_data.Date.value_counts().compute()`

and the output looks like this:

`2019-01-25    291288
2019-01-11    290607
2019-01-31    283724
2019-01-17    283409
2019-01-24    280805
2019-01-10    280648
Name: Date, dtype: int64`

The question is how would I sort this by the first column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way** is to call *sort_index* **after** *compute*.

```
taxi_data.Date.value_counts().compute().sort_index()
```

Now (after *value_counts*) the result is relatively small, so there is no need
to sort it at the *dask* level.

**Another option** (to do it at the *dask* level anyway) is to:

- convert to a DataFrame (with a single column),
- reset the index, so that the index becomes a **regular** column (this new
  column is by default named as *index*),
- set the index back to *index* column, this is the moment the sort
  actually takes place,
- (optionally) *squeeze* it to convert back to a *Series*,
- compute the result.

So the whole code can be:

```
taxi_data.Date.value_counts().to_frame()\
    .reset_index().set_index('index').squeeze().compute()
```

Comment: This is fantastic solution. One more question - what if I want to sort by the count column instead of the Date column? Do I need to name that column and then set_index to that column?

Comment: I assume it is easier (and more natural) to take the first of my approaches.
So after *value_counts().compute()* the result is a "pandasonic" *Series*,
so then  you can use whatever *Pandas* methods you wish.
In this case: 1. If you want **descending** sort, no action is needed (you have the descending sort right now). 2. If you want **ascending** sort it is enough to call *sort_values()*.